# pipeline with dynamic choice parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a stage in a pipeline where I use this

```
build job: 'Myjob', parameters:[[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: '´myxxx', value: xxx]]
```

So if I want to send a class for my dynamic choice parameter what should I use as a class? I cant seem to find anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

Just send a string. When setting up the Choice parameter, you have to provide a list, but when when you are setting the parameter when you run the build, the single item in the list is just a string. This is the same thing. Just give it a string.